Where does Outlook store mail and autocomplete addresses in Microsoft Outlook for Mac?
About 2 years ago MS rolled out a new interface but it still resides under "Outlook 16". So if you search around for files or anything like that, it'll be referencing how "Old" outlook behaves on macOS. When you're in the application, you click the word "Outlook" and it says "✅ New Outlook".
Anyway, I can find the old data. It resides here:
/Users/<YOUR USER NAME>/Library/Group\ Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Outlook/Outlook\ 15\ Profiles/Main\ Profile/Data
I connect to Outlook.sqlite using DbVisualizer and voila I can see mail, contacts, etc. However the last email it shows is from ~2022 which was likely when I switched over to the new interface.
So, where is Outlook storing its database now?!
Ultimately I'm trying to find a way to export my Auto-Complete list from the database, but can't find the DB to begin with.

I didn't find any article mentioned where the auto-compete list is stored. I'm afraid that you need to switch to Legacy Outlook to use that feature.

This is ultimately what I ended up doing. Switched back over to the old interface and rebuilt the DB. All of my mail is now in Outlook.sqlite

If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.
